# Can a saved Azure Spatial Anchor be saved(updated) again?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I am wondering whether it is possible to 'update' a saved Azure Spatial Anchor. I created an anchor, saved it, then close the session, then start a new session, as I have the reference to the saved anchor(CloudSpatialAnchor object), I saved the anchor again in a different position, then I got this Exception:

[image]

So, I assume it is not allowed to 'update' an anchor, the official document didn't mention it. If I get it right, we need to delete the anchor and then create a new one in the different position? Please confirm.

Comment: I tried exatly the same and opened an issue at the git repository of azure spartial anchors. No answer from microsoft until now. 

https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/58

Comment: I also opened the same but more detailed question like you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569981/update-a-microsoft-azurespatialanchor-not-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the anchors cannot be moved or updated once they are created. You will need to create a new anchor for the new location and delete the old one if you don't want it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I think the same. It is currently the only approach which is working at the moment.

Comment: Still the same in 2023 ?

Comment: yes, that is still the case @ChocooPanda