# Does Azure Spatial Anchors refine its internal model on every user session?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

Does Azure Spatial Anchors accurate its internal model on every user session?

In a scenario that lasts a long time, it could be possible that elements change its position over the time.

Azure Spatial Anchors use the user session to update and refine the internal model of the scenario?, or use only the model created at first when we add Spatial Anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Spatial Anchors stores the information or state of the space at the time the anchor is created. Anchors can not be modified/updated. If you need to update the anchor you will need [to delete the initial one and create a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721386/5420074).